# C# - VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled shows a different dialog with OpenFileDialog call

Tags: c#, view, menu, openfiledialog

Setting VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled in code shows a completely different dialog for OpenFileDialog call than when done without a VisualStyleState. The drop down for "View Menu" shows a vertical bar without text and the left browser pane is gone.

[Image showing problem with Visual Style State set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbwds.png)

In our application we need to set Styles as we have developed custom ones.

Issue reproducible on Windows 10 Build 1709, .Net 4.6.1 and default C# forms application. Also reproduced on Windows 10 build 1809. Works fine with all earlier versions of Windows.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        fileDialog.Filter = " (*.sql)|*.sql";
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Without VisualStyleState set, the OpenFileDialog shows a completely different UI, with browser pane on the left side and all drop downs work as expected.

[Image showing default behaviour of OpenFileDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDxlC.png)

Any pointers to fix this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one situation a dialog is rendered as an old style dialog and the other one as so-called “Vista-style” dialog:

- old style
  [image: old style]
- Vistay style
  [image: old style]

Here's the code the drives this decision:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,986

A type of a dialog depends on whether `VisualStyleState.ClientAreaEnabled` is set or not. Because you set the style to `VisualStyleState.NonClientAreaEnabled` the app falls back to the old-style.

There is [`AutoUpgradeEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.autoupgradeenabled?view=netframework-4.8) property that allow rendering the dialog as Vista-style, you could try setting it to `true` and see if it helps.